# Get Names of Array of Objects without Looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of country objects `(countries)` and I'm trying to get just an array of the `String` names, so from this example:[image]

Just: `['Canada', 'USA', ..]` etc.

I'm trying to do this with

```
const getNames = (countries) => countries.map(({ Name }) => Name);
```

but I can't seem to get it. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the result when you run your code? Are you wanting it to be a function?

Comment: What do you mean 'I can't seem to get it', did you get a result different from from what you expected? What was it?

Comment: How do you call the function `getNames`? Please replace the image with a text-based [mcve]

Comment: That function should work. `countryNames = getNames(countries)`

Comment: Wouldn't the current function return the whole object, rather than `Object.name`?

Comment: @user1599011 what makes you think that?

Comment: @user1599011 - the dummy param in the op is being assigned with (the relatively new) destructuring assignment.  ({ Name }) plucks the name from the passed object

Comment: I just noticed the {} in the params for the arrow function, which I think threw me off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quite close to getting it right; just remove `(countries) =>`  and you're good to go.

```
const getNames = countries.map(({ Name }) => Name);
```

Alternatively, you can keep your code, which is a function. To get the names of the countries - `coNames` - call the function and pass `countries` as a parameter.

```
const getNames = (countries) => countries.map(({ Name }) => Name); 
const countries = [{id: ...., Name:.........}];
const coNames = getNames( countries );
```

Your code is equivalent to:

```
const getNames = function( countries ) {
    return countries.map(function({Name}) {
        return Name;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Just this?

```js
const getNames = countries.map(c => c.Name);
```

Comment: Agree, but I don't see how this will work when the OP's equivalent doesn't

Answer (score 0):

While topic says "without" looping, actually you can't. Map method also creates internal looping algorithm. So basically you can do something very simple and really efficient like standard `for` loop.

```js
// Array of objects
const arr = [
  { id: 1, Name: "Canada", isSelected: false },
  { id: 2, Name: "USA", isSelected: false },
  { id: 3, Name: "India", isSelected: false }
];

// Function to get all params by name
const getAllParam = (arr, param, res = []) => {
  for(const e of arr) if(e[param]) res.push(e[param]);
  return res;
};

// Get all params with "Name" key
const res = getAllParam(arr, "Name");

// Test
console.log(res);
```